# CCMenuItemLabel – "The block will be 'copied'."

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c-blocks

Simple question regarding the statement “The block will be ‘copied’.” I am not quite comfortable with my understanding and use of blocks in objective-c, what does ‘copied’ mean? If someone can explain or point me to a resource which can, I would appreciate it. Thank you

*This method is from the Cocos2d documentation.

```
+ (id) itemWithLabel:(CCNode< CCLabelProtocol, CCRGBAProtocol > *) label
block:(id sender) block
```

creates a CCMenuItemLabel with a Label and a block to execute. The block will be “copied”.

Comment: the block is sent the 'copy' message allowing the original block object to deallocate respectively to be reused for other items using a block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks are something like structure which contains a set of informations like the pointer to the function.
By default when you create a block, it s created on the Stack, you must copy it to the Heap to be able to use it outside the stack Call.
In this example this method will return an item object and will copy the block parameter(Probably still on the stack) to the Heap to be able to use it if needed.